# how to render argmax symbol in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I am trying to reproduce this formula coming from the [CMU Machine Learning lecture](https://youtu.be/tpmdcJYnAyQ?t=273).

[image]

this code

```
$\hat{\theta}^{MLE} =\argmax_{\theta} \operatorname {P}(D|\theta)=\dfrac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_0}$
```

generates this one

[image]

in Jupyter notebook (Mathjax)

how to render that argmax symbol properly in jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\underset` command

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_SVG-full" type="text/javascript"></script>


$$\hat{\theta}^{MLE} =\underset{\theta}{\operatorname{arg max}}{P}(D|\theta)=\dfrac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_0}$$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The last line works well on its own. What is the first line doing?

Comment: Sorry, I should have told you not to consider this line. It just imports mathjax libraries to create a functional html snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use

`$$ \arg\max_{\theta} $$`

Comment: Why? What's the benefit of this approach?

Comment: Personally, I think this is earsier (`\arg\max_{\theta}` is much shorter than `\underset{\theta}{\operatorname{arg max}}`).

Also, this approach does exactly what is shown in the picture of that lecture ($\theta$ in the center of `max`), but if you want $\theta$ to be in the center of `argmax`, then I guess you should use the answer in the first answer.

Comment: This centers `\theta` under `\max`, which is confusing.

Comment: ..that's where it belongs. arg and max are separate operations, and only max accepts a parameter, so that's where it should go.